# Stopwords Remaining in Corpus After Cleaning

Tags: r

I am attempting to remove the stopword "the" from my corpus, however not all instances are being removed.

```
library(RCurl)
library(tm)

url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angerhang/statsTutorial/master/src/textMining/data/1.txt"
file1 <- getURL(url)
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angerhang/statsTutorial/master/src/textMining/data/2.txt"
file2 <- getURL(url)
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angerhang/statsTutorial/master/src/textMining/data/3.txt"
file3 <- getURL(url)


shakespeare <- VCorpus(VectorSource(c(file1,file2,file3)))

list<-inspect(
  DocumentTermMatrix(shakespeare,list(dictionary = c("the","thee")))
)
shakespeare <- tm_map(shakespeare, stripWhitespace)
shakespeare <- tm_map(shakespeare, stemDocument)
shakespeare <- tm_map(shakespeare, removePunctuation)
tm_map(shakespeare, content_transformer(tolower))
#taken directly from tm documentation
shakespeare <- tm_map(shakespeare, removeWords, c(stopwords("english"),"the"))
list<-inspect(
  DocumentTermMatrix(shakespeare,list(dictionary = c("the","thee")))
)
```

The first inspect call reveals:

```
    Terms
Docs   the thee
   1 11665  752
   2 11198  660
   3  4866  382
```

And the second, after cleaning:

```
    Terms
Docs  the thee
   1 1916 1298
   2 1711 1140
   3  760  740
```

What am I missing here about the logic of removeWords that it would ignore all these instances of "the"?

### EDIT

I was able to get the instances of "the" down to below 1000 by a slight call change and making the removewords call the very first cleaning step:

```
shakespeare <- tm_map(shakespeare, removeWords, c(stopwords("english"),"the","The"))
```

Which gets me down to:

```
Docs the thee
   1 145  752
   2 130  660
   3  71  382
```

Still though, I'd like to know why I can't seem to eliminate them all.

Comment: Just a typo. You are not setting anything to lowercase. "tm_map(shakespeare, content_transformer(tolower))" should be "shakespeare = tm_map(shakespeare, content_transformer(tolower))"

Comment: @Koot6133 thanks, any idea on why I still have a remaining instances of "the" though? Even when I call removewords first and include both "the" and "The", it still doesn't remove all instances of that word.

Comment: You have to be carefull with the order in which you do the steps. your version before the edit results in 0 times the. I guess that in your edited version punctuation is causing problems. I guess '',the'' and "the:" will not be removed from the text, but the punctuation will be removed in a later step. Which causes instances of 'the' in your dtm.

Comment: @Koot6133 Can you provide reproducible code if you got it to work? I cannot get 0 instances of "the".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hereby reproducable code which leads to 0 instances of "the". I solved your typo and used your code from before the edit.

```
library(RCurl)
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)

url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angerhang/statsTutorial/master/src/textMining/data/1.txt"
file1 <- getURL(url)
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angerhang/statsTutorial/master/src/textMining/data/2.txt"
file2 <- getURL(url)
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angerhang/statsTutorial/master/src/textMining/data/3.txt"
file3 <- getURL(url)


shakespeare <- VCorpus(VectorSource(c(file1,file2,file3)))

list<-inspect(
  DocumentTermMatrix(shakespeare,list(dictionary = c("the","thee")))
)
```

leads to:

```
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 3, terms: 2)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 6/0
Sparsity           : 0%
Maximal term length: 4
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
    Terms
Docs   the thee
   1 11665  752
   2 11198  660
   3  4866  382
```

and after cleaning and solving the typo:

```
shakespeare <- tm_map(shakespeare, stripWhitespace)
shakespeare <- tm_map(shakespeare, stemDocument)
shakespeare <- tm_map(shakespeare, removePunctuation)
shakespeare = tm_map(shakespeare, content_transformer(tolower)) ## FIXED TYPO
#taken directly from tm documentation
shakespeare <- tm_map(shakespeare, removeWords, c(stopwords("english"),"the"))
list<-inspect(
  DocumentTermMatrix(shakespeare,list(dictionary = c("the","thee")))
)
```

it leads to:

```
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 3, terms: 2)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 3/3
Sparsity           : 50%
Maximal term length: 4
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
    Terms
Docs the thee
   1   0 1298
   2   0 1140
   3   0  740
```